# Python QueryFrame returns None, but C++ bindings work

Tags: python, opencv

In OpenCV 2.3.1 (built from source) on Ubuntu 10.04, the C++ fragment

```
cvNamedWindow("Camera", 1);
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
while (1) {
  IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
  cvShowImage("Camera", frame);
  key = cvWaitKey(10);
  ...
```

will open up a window and show video from my ThinkPad camera, but

```
import cv2.cv as cv
# or import cv
cv.NamedWindow("Camera", 1)
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
while True:
  frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
  cv.ShowImage("Camera", frame)
  key = cv.WaitKey(10)
  ...
```

fails (the window is gray), because `cv.QueryFrame` returns `None` (and the light on the laptop camera doesn't come on.)

Any idea what may be going on here (and how I might remedy it)? `cv.QueryFrame` works when displaying `.jpg`, so this seems to be a camera issue.

Comment: Have you tried passing different numbers to `CaptureFromCAM`? You should try explicitly selecting a camera, even if there is only one.

Comment: Tried -1, 0, and 1. Same result. (And it's the only camera.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815187/opencv-python-queryframe-return-none which fixed it for me (it takes a little while for the camera to fully turn on).

Answer (score 3):

Found a workaround, via [opencv+python+linux+webcam = cannot capture frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717743/opencvpythonlinuxwebcam-cannot-capture-frames), which I'll leave here for posterity.

Install `lib4vl` (`apt-get install libv4l-dev`) and in the `cmake` step of building `OpenCV`, pass `-D WITH_4VL=ON`. (I'd been building with that OFF.)

Why C++ works without `lib4vl` but the Python bindings require it to work with a webcam is a puzzle, which perhaps some OpenCV-knowledgable person can explain. I'd love to hear an explanation.